# Android web app screen css help

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications

I have a mobile application that I am building, it is made to support Android, iPhone and probably Blackberry.  Most of the CSS and formatting is coded on a 1024px.  I have formatted the site using an iPhone because it was in hand.  After trying the site on an Android, the site seems to load as if the phone believes it is a full screen.  So I only see a part of the page.

I use this line to have the app load correctly on the iPhone:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

Are there any methods for Android?  If I remove the `user-scalable=no` I can double tap the Android screen and it will be the correct size, but ideally that isn't how the site should load.